# Dynamic memory allocation for 3D array using array of pointers method in C

Tags: c

I am getting the segmentation faults 
Unable to rectify it...........

If function is used (multi line commented at the top) im finding segemntation fault
With the present code i am unable to guess the segmentation fault.

If fixed size of string like malloc is used then it works very fine.

```
//Array of pointers method
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int count=0;
char *** input(char ***);
void print(char ***);
/*
void *allocate(char *p,int j)
{
    int i=0;
    do
    {
        p=realloc(p,i+1);
//      printf("p[count][j]= %u\n",p);
        p[i]=getchar();
    }while(p[i++]!=10);
    p[i-1]='\0';
    return p;
 }*/
void save(char ***p)
{
    int j,i;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("Secret.c","w");
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
      for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
      fprintf(fp,"%s\n",p[i][j]);

  } 
 fclose(fp);

}
void main()
{
    char ***a=0;
    char ch;
//  printf("a = %u\n ",a);
    while(1)
    {
        if(count>0)
        {
            printf("a = %lu\n",a);
            printf("*a = %lu\n",sizeof(*a));
            printf("**a = %lu\n",sizeof(**a));
            printf("***a = %lu\n",***a);
        }
        printf("\n\n\t\t\tMenu\n\n\n");
        printf("i . input\ns . save\np . print\nq . quit");
        printf("\n\nEnter your choice : ");
        scanf(" %c",&ch);
        getchar();
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 'i': a=input(a);break;
            case 's': save(a);
            case 'p': print(a);break;
            case 'q': return;
            default : printf("\n\n\t\t!!! Invalid choice  \n\n");
        }
    }
}
char *** input(char ***p)
{
    int i=0,j;

//  printf("p = %u\n ",p);
    p=realloc(p,sizeof(p)*(count+1));
//  printf("p = %u\n ",p);
//  printf("sizeof(p) = %u\n",sizeof(p));
//  printf("*p = %u\n ",*p);
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        p[count]=realloc(p[count],sizeof(p)*(j+1));
//      printf("*p = %u\n ",*p);
//      printf("**p = %u\n ",**p);
        i=0;
        if(j==0)
            printf("Enter the %d name : ",count+1);
        else if (j==1)
            printf("Enter the %d mobile no : ",count+1);
        else
        printf("Enter the %d E-mail : ",count+1);    
//      p[count][j]=malloc(20);
//      gets(p[count][j]);      

//      p[count][j]=allocate(p[count][j],j);
        do
        {
            p[count][j]=realloc(p[count][j],i+1);
            p[count][j][i]=getchar();
        }while(p[count][j][i++]!=10);
        p[count][j][i-1]='\0';
//      printf("***p = %u %s\n ",***p,***p);
    }
    count++;
    return p;   

}
void print(char ***p)
{
    int j,i;
    for(i=0;i<count;i++,printf("\n"))
        for( j=0;j<3;j++)
            printf("p[%d][%d] : %s\t",i,j,p[i][j]);

}
```

Comment: `p=realloc(p,sizeof(p)*(count+1))` I am pretty sure you should take a size of something else than `p` here...

Comment: You want to allocate *some reasonably anticipated number of* `p` to begin with and then `realloc` *some reasonably anticipated additional number of* `p` if your original limit is reached. Do not `realloc` for every element you add. (you can, but your are killing your efficiency with repeated calls to `realloc`)

Comment: Obligatory 3-star-programmer joke: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer

Answer (score 2):

Some general guidelines:

You want to (re)allocate N instances of the type that `p` *points to*, not N instances of the type of `p`, so the operand to `sizeof` should be `*p`:

```
p = malloc( sizeof *p * N ); // operand of sizeof is *p, not p
                   ^^
```

If `p` is an array of pointers, use

```
p[i] = malloc( sizeof *p[i] * N );
```

Also, remember that a `realloc` call will return `NULL` if the memory cannot be extended, so you don't want to assign the result directly back to `p`, otherwise you risk losing the pointer to the memory you've already allocated, leading to a memory leak.  Assign the result back to a temporary of the same type as `p`:

```
T *tmp = realloc( p, sizeof *p * M );
if ( tmp )
{
  p = tmp;
}
```

`realloc` is a potentially expensive call, and lots of little `realloc`s can lead to internal memory fragmentation.  It's better to allocate in larger chunks than to extend one element at a time. For reading an individual input, you could so something like this:

```
char *getNextLine( FILE *inputStream )
{
  char staticBuffer[SOME_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
  char *dynamicBuffer = calloc( SOME_BUFFER_SIZE, sizeof *dynamicBuffer );
  size_t dynamicBufferSize = SOME_BUFFER_SIZE;
  bool done = false;

  /**
   * If the initial allocation fails, we have real problems.
   */
  assert( dynamicBuffer != NULL );

  while ( !done && fgets( staticBuffer, sizeof staticBuffer, stdin ) )
  {
    /**
     * Check for the newline; if it's there, remove it and set the
     * done flag to exit the loop.
     */
    char *newline = strchr( staticBuffer, '\n' );
    if ( (done = (newline != NULL)) )
    {
       *newline = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Do we need to extend our dynamic buffer?
     */
    if ( strlen( dynamicBuffer ) + strlen( staticBuffer ) > dynamicBufferSize )
    {
      /**
       * Yes.  Double the size of the dynamic buffer.
       */
      char *tmp = realloc( dynamicBuffer, sizeof *dynamicBuffer * ( dynamicBufferSize * 2 ) );
      if ( tmp )
      {
        dynamicBuffer = tmp;
        dynamicBufferSize *= 2;
      }
      else
      {
        // could not extend buffer, print an error and return what we have
        fprintf( stderr, "ERR: Could not extend dynamic input buffer\n" );
        return dynamicBuffer;
      }
    }

    strcat( dynamicBuffer, staticBuffer );
  }

  return dynamicBuffer;
}
```

Comment: But if i use it like fixed size i.e //      p[count][j]=malloc(20);
then no segmentation fault occurs
If p is an array of pointers, use

p[i] = malloc( sizeof *p[i] * N );
that is what i used  p[count]=realloc(p[count],sizeof(p)*(j+1));
wats the difference among the two above statements